# How to update emoji in vader lexicon?

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, vader

I want to update the chart up and chart down emojis sentiment values in the vader lexicon. Seeing this post ([VaderSentiment: unable to update emoji sentiment score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63249001/vadersentiment-unable-to-update-emoji-sentiment-score)) I have tried to replicate it but with no success:

```
new_words = {
    "chart decreasing" : -1,
    "" : -1
}
analyzer.lexicon.update(new_words)

analyzer.polarity_scores("")
```

Result:
`{'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 1.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': 0.0}`

It should show `neg: 1.0`, as I have just updated the lexicon.

Any ideas how to update the values?

Answer (score 1):

```
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

new_words = {
    'decreasing': -4.0,
}

sia = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
sia.lexicon.update(new_words)
sia.polarity_scores('')
```

Comment: could you please explain your answer? code only answers are not really preferred on SO.

Comment: It's not like he is asking about an algorithm. Explanation: you should use 'decreasing' instead of "chart decreasing"

Comment: how do you find the names of the emoji? For example this one was listed as `chart decreasing` in the vader emoji lexicon - https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment/blob/master/vaderSentiment/emoji_utf8_lexicon.txt

Comment: would your answer not also impact the word `decreasing` as apposed to just the emoji.

Comment: it would appear that most of the emojis seem to take the first word used in the name, e.g. `sleeping face` would respond to `sleeping`