# VaderSentiment: emoji analyzer does not work in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, emoji, sentiment-analysis, vader

I am trying to do some sentiment analysis on r/wallstreetbets content and would also like to use the meaning of emojis.

Here is my code:

```
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

wsb_lingo = {
    "bullish": 4.0,
    "bearish": -4.0,
    "bagholder": -4.0,
    "BTFD": 4.0,
    "FD": 4.0,
    "diamond hands": 0.0,
    "paper hands": 0.0,
    "DD": 4.0,
    "GUH": -4.0,
    "pump": 4.0,
    "dump": -4.0,
    "gem stone": 4.0, # emoji
    "rocket": 4.0, # emoji
    "andromeda": 0.0,
    "to the moon": 4.0,
    "stonks": -4.0,
    "tendies": 4.0,
    "buy": 4.0,
    "sell": -4.0,
    "hold": 4.0,
    "short": 4.0,
    "long": 4.0,
    "overvalued": -4.0,
    "undervalued": 4.0,
    "calls": 4.0,
    "call": 4.0,
    "puts": -4.0,
    "put": -4.0,
}

sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
sid.lexicon.update(wsb_lingo)

# Test
print(sid.polarity_scores(''))
print(sid.polarity_scores(''))
```

The output is given below:

```
{'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': 0.0}
{'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': 0.0}
```

How is it possible that it's unable to give any sentiment for emojis (e.g., due to Jupyter Notebook)? Am I forgetting something here? All libraries are up-to-date.

Comment: So this is working when running it in a script (not notebook)? According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63249245/9478384), it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I use `vaderSentiment` instead of `nltk.sentiment.vader` it works for me

```
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

new = { "rocket": 4.0 }
sia = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
sia.polarity_scores('')
# Outputs: {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 1.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': 0.0}

sia.lexicon.update(new)
sia.polarity_scores('')
# Outputs: {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.0, 'pos': 1.0, 'compound': 0.7184}
```

See also [this issue](https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment/issues/63)